# Wifi not working after updating ubuntu to 14.04

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager

**SOLVED: Turned out to be problem with secure boot, refer to solution here** "[Why do I get "Required key not available" when install 3rd party kernel modules or after a kernel upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762254/why-do-i-get-required-key-not-available-when-install-3rd-party-kernel-modules)"

I just got my Dell Inspiration 15 and it had ubuntu installed on it by default, I updated it by running the following:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

It ran fine, finished updating over Wifi and asked me to restart, after the reset, My wifi is not working and not even showing up in ifconfig or anywhere.

The output of :

```
lspci -nn | grep 280
lsusb
rfkill list all


batee5a@Bat335a:~$ lspci -nn | grep 0280
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 3160 [8086:08b3] (rev 83)
batee5a@Bat335a:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1bcf:2b90 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
batee5a@Bat335a:~$ rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

I've tried solutions in other threads and non worked thats why I'm posting this here as a new thread, Any help please?

**EDIT:** Further Results of codes.

```
batee5a@Bat335a:~$ sudo modprobe iwlwifi
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'iwlwifi': Required key not available
batee5a@Bat335a:~$ dmesg | grep iwl
batee5a@Bat335a:~$
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of these terminal commands: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi` and also:  `dmesg | grep iwl`

Comment: @chili555 Done.

Comment: You installed a custom package. Please post output of `dkms status; uname -a` command TO YOUR QUESTION.

Comment: @Pilot6 It is solved, turned out to be a problem with Secure Boot.

Comment: This is a wrong solution. It was a problem with SecureBoot. But with 16.04 you do not need the custom module.

Comment: @Pilot6 it appears to be the result of a Dell solution that I think we have seen before.   Ahmed A. Sherif please post results for Pilot6's inquiry as I would like to find this package and look at the source code